# Clear the data from the control after the insert the row?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm using aspxgridview and after adding operation by using `RowInserting` event and I don't use the

```
gridView.CancelEdit();
```

becuase I need the addform still apperaing to insert another row.

My problem is :  how can I clean the data from the control in the addform until I can insert the new data for the second row ??

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solve of my problem by using ASPxClientEdit.ClearEditorsInContainer :

clientsideevents EndCallback  ="function(s, e) {
                          if (s.cpIsUpdated)
                              { 
                                   ASPxClientEdit.ClearEditorsInContainer(ContainerId);
                               }
                             }"

and add the following code after the RowInserting event:

```
        gridView.JSProperties["cpIsUpdated"] = true;
```

thanks